# how can i accomplish the code below without custom vars in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

```
            {%  for voter in opt.voterlog_set.all  %}
                {% if user.id != voter.voter.id %}
                    <span data-url="{% url vote %}" data-id="{{ opt.id }}" class="button">vote</span>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

In the code above I want to show the vote option once only if the current user hasn't already voted. The code above prints out the vote option multiple times (once for each entry in voterlog). Django doesn't let me set a custom variable such as a boolean which I can you use to toggle a hasVoted variable. How can I fix this code using Django templates?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This code should be moved to the view. You are doing too much for what django considers template responsibility

Comment: I moved the logic into the view as suggested. Turned out to be pretty simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you mention, there's no way to set state in a Django template, there isn't any sane way to do this if you don't have access to the view code.  If you do have access to the view code, the easiest solution -- and, all in all, the most correct solution -- is to set a context variable `user_has_voted` in the view, instead of iterating through the voterlogs in the template.

But, if you don't have access to the view, you'll have to use a hack involving some client-side code, like rendering Javascript to set the necessary state and then adding some further Javascript to check that state and adjust the DOM after the page has loaded.

It seems like your logic is wrong though.  You'd need something that sets state if and only if the current user IS found in the loop, like this:

```
        {%  for voter in opt.voterlog_set.all  %}
            {% if user.id == voter.voter.id %}
            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.user_has_voted = true;
            </script>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <script type="text/javascript">
        if( !window.user_has_voted ) {
          document.write('<span data-url="{% url vote %}" data-id="{{ opt.id }}" class="button">vote</span>');
        }
        </script>
```

Note that this is a particularly nasty hack -- it should only ever be used if you only have access to the templates and have no control over the context variables being sent in to the templates.

Comment: This isn't a django template solution. Its a javascript client side solution. Just wanted to clarify. It reinforces the fact that this solution should be moved completely to the view.

Comment: I rephrased a bit to try to clarify that it's not a pure server side solution.  Certainly it's not a good solution.  :-)  But I do occasionally have to rely on this kind of pattern, when working with hosted applications that give me full template access (e.g. through a web interface for admins) but no control over the view code.  So, while I agree 100% that the solution should be moved to the view, this sort of template-driven-client-side-scripting hack is sometimes the only viable solution.

Comment: Its good info, no doubt. I'm just hoping that ultimately the OP moves this to view if they have full access to their own project. There are convienience views that render models directly to views, but to do it manually and do model queries in your template seems out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not what you want, but what about creating the list of voters in your view, and add it to template context. Then

```
{% if user not in voters %}
    "user is allowed to vote"
{% endif %}
```